Non-SDK API Usage Violation - Android App - Firebase Test Lab
When I test my app on Firebase Test Lab I get following warnings under Test Issues.
Non-SDK API Usage Violation
Your app uses 10 non-SDK interfaces, which are incompatible with Android P+.
Landroid/os/Trace;->isTagEnabled(J)Z
Landroid/os/Trace;->asyncTraceBegin(JLjava/lang/String;I)V
Landroid/os/Trace;->traceBegin(JLjava/lang/String;)V
Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V
Landroid/os/Trace;->asyncTraceEnd(JLjava/lang/String;I)V
Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl;
Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String;
Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I
Landroid/os/Trace;->traceEnd(J)V

Searched google and stack overflow, didn't find any solution. I am not sure how to fix these, please help.
